# AWS Redshift to Postgres federated query failure

Tags: amazon-redshift

I've had a look here but can't find an answer to my problem. I'm trying to run a federated query on Redshift (to Postgres) from DataGrip but it errors out with -

> [HY000][100071] [Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. No output location provided. An output location is required either through the Workgroup result configuration setting or as an API input. [Execution ID not available] com.simba.athena.amazonaws.services.athena.model.InvalidRequestException: No output location provided. An output location is required either through the Workgroup result configuration setting or as an API input. (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 6b51efb8-5f90-46c0-abc9-10da282926fd; Proxy: null)

Should I setup something in the AWS Athena Console before running the SQLs?
Others in my team are able to query the table fine so I am at my wits end trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Appreicate any help, thank you.